# How to update Vue component when promise resolve AND passing props to nested children

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have parent and child components. Parent's data is populated after an ajax call, that I want to pass to child as a props.

I tried different solutions, I will post two, but not yet working : could you please pin-point the error?

The component does react to changes. I also need to ensure that props are correctly passed to child and its nested children.

Attempts:

- If I don't use `'v-if'` directive, I will get an error for `:query` is
  passed through as null.
- So I use `v-if` (see version below)
  and update the rendering, but it does not react and stay empty (even
  though data is properly updated).
- I also tried to initialize the query data as computed without using
  the v-if directive, because after all I just need to cache the result
  of the premise.
- I also tried to emit an event on a bus, but the component does not
  react.
- Finally I tried to make the component reactive by making use of a
  `:key` (e.g. `:key="ready"`) that should make the component reactive when
  the `:key` changes. But still no effect.

Template:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="isLoaded()">
      <input>
      <metroline></metroline>
      <grid :query="query"></grid>
  </div>
</template>
```

script:

```
export default {

data() {
  return {
    ready : false,
    query : null
  }
},
components : {
  metroline : Metroline,
  grid : Grid
},
methods: {

    isLoaded() {
      return this.ready
    },

    firstQuery( uid, limit, offset) {

      var url = // my url
      
      // using Jquery to handle cross origin issues, solving with jsonp callback...
      
      return $.ajax({
        url : url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'callback',
        crossDomain: true 
        
        })

    }

},
created() {
  var vm = self;

  this.firstQuery(...)
      .then(function(data){
                 this.query = data;
                 console.log('firstQuery', this.query);

                 // attempts to pass through the query
                 // bus.$emit('add-query', this.query);

                 this.ready = true;
                 self.isLoaded(); // using a self variable, temporarily, jquery deferred messed up with this; however the this.query of vue instance is properly updated
                 
            })
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In created hook assign the component instance `this` to a a variable called `that` and access it inside the callback because in the callback you're outside the vue component context (`this`):

```
created() {
  var vm = self;
  var that=this;
  this.firstQuery(...)
      .then(function(data){
                 that.query = data;
                 console.log('firstQuery', this.query);

              

                 that.ready = true;
                 self.isLoaded(); 
            })
}
}
```

Comment: oh thank you @Boussadjra Brahim I made confusion with the 'this' object in the promise.  I was using `"console.log('firstQuery', this.query)` inside the promise to check if updated, but instead I was creating just a property on the promise.

Comment: p.s. I looked at your profile - you might want to add demos at the components' git-pages (vueye etc.)

Comment: you're welcome and thanks for visiting my profile, if you look at the components repositories you'll find the demos